# Where should I put android button function

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I know how to make button in XML but I don't know where should I put my function. Should I put it on layout or drawable? How to call my script if I press that button.

Answer (score 0):

A typical code snippet for the class related to your XML file would be the following:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
    }
});
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html